# How to properly set self-referencing in Entity Framework 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to set up my database using the Entity Framework 7 and to add a self-referencing many-to-many relationship. I have this class in my project:

```
public class Customer : User
    {
        // ...
        [JsonIgnore]
        public ICollection<Customer> Friends { get; set; } = new List<Customer>();
        // ...
    }
```

Since I am new to EF I was wondering what is the best way to set self-referencing? Will EF do the job by default or should I add something to *OnModelCreating* method?

Comment: Have you tried it? Have you checked the generated database structure?

Comment: @GuruStron By default nothing was created. For other basic many-to-many relationships in my project, EF created junction tables, but not for this. However, I have achieved what I was looking for with this snippet below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to OnModelCreating method and I achieve what I was looking for.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Friends)
    .WithMany()
    .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
        "CustomerFriend",
        j => j
            .HasOne<Customer>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("CustomerId"),
        j => j
            .HasOne<Customer>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("FriendId")
    );
```